# how to split equation on two lines

Tags: latex, biblatex

I wrote the following two equations in latex, but the problem is when I run the code, both equation are written on the same line

how can I split them on two lines

```
\begin{equation}
N = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon) \\
E = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
\label{eq:gps_to_cartesian}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `amsmath` package for such needs. It provides tools to work with multi-line equations, bundled in its equation-like environments. It is a standard package which is in most installations.

For two independent equations, listed below each other and aligned on `=` sign

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align} \label{eq:gps_to_cartesian}
N = &  R * cos(lat) * sin(lon) \\
E = &  R * cos(lat) * cos(lon).
\end{align}
```

Additional alignment points can be set up with additional `&`. Equation numbering can be suppressed on individual lines by adding `\notag`. More tweaking can be done.

Note that there are other environments for multi-line equations, to suit different uses.

Here is a clear page on [Aligning Equations](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) and here is the official [User's Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) (pdf).

---

The original way was to use `eqnarray` for this, replaced long ago by `amsmath`, but it can still step in if for some reason the package cannot be used.